# Loading remote images from base url using loadHTMLString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting HTML String as response from my server which include an image tag. The image location is www.example.com/image.jpg/ I am giving @"www.example.com" as base url. But I am not getting the image in the webView which i show by loading this html string. 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you are not getting the image name from server how will you show....?

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: I am getting the name and exact location of the image from the server. But it is not being shown

Comment: @ManojThomas- show the code the response

Comment: [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com"]];

HtmlString contains the following,
<div><img id="image" style="width:240.00px;height:155.31px;" src="https://www.example.com/image.png" /></div>

Comment: Has this been solved?